# Luxon DateTime.fromObject is ignoring zone option when I pass year, month, & day options. How I stop it to override the zone?

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

When I use DateTime fromObject with only time options I get the expected output with the correct timezone offset at the end. However when I provide the year, month, & day options is revert to using the utc timezone offset ignoring the zone param I have passed to it. I need the timezone offset as I am comparing times from potentially different timezones.

```
DateTime.fromObject({
    hour: 10,
    minute: 26,
    second: 6
}, { zone: "Europe/London" })
```

output
`2023-10-03T10:26:06.000+01:00`

However when I pass a the date values it removed the zone

```
DateTime.fromObject({
    year: 2007,
    month: 12,
    day: 25,
    hour: 10,
    minute: 26,
    second: 6
}, { zone: "Europe/London" })
```

output
`2007-12-25T10:26:06.000+00:00`
expected
`2007-12-25T10:26:06.000+01:00`

Addtionally I tried manually creating a iso string

```
DateTime.fromISO("2007-12-25T10:26:06.000+01:00")
```

output
`2007-12-25T09:26:06.000+00:00`

Comment: December in England is winter, so no DST (so GMT +0). Daylight saving in 2023 ends on 29 October, so currently British Summer Time, +1.

Comment: oh my god, I typed in a random month to test this without thinking that the month wouldn't be in DST. Thank you so much